# Is it possible to run 2 circleCI workflows independently - one with each commit and one daily?

Tags: yaml, circleci

Currently, the project is using v2 of circleCI and it doesn't have any workflows, just 1 job.

I want to create 2 workflows(one is the old job and one is the new one for my integration tests) in config.yml file, but I want the first job to run with each commit and the second one to run only once daily

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Create one regular Workflow and one Scheduled Workflow. The former will run on commit while the former would run on a cron. https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#scheduling-a-workflow